# using rails for a very thin application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been working on a large website with Ruby on Rails for more than 2 years now and found it really convenient and easy to code a web application or service. Now I want to build a really thin web service: no DB, no front end 1-2 controllers with 2-3 actions each.

When I invoke `rails new`, it sort of "scaffolding" a large application structure, there is any way to get the default large structure replaced for a small service suitable structure with rails? (btw, If you think I don't need to use rails for such a project you're welcome to explain why.  )

Comment: Sounds like a job for `sinatra`: http://www.sinatrarb.com/

Comment: You can try sinatra or padrino (or one of a few other frameworks). They're lighter than rails

Comment: You shoud give a try Sinatra, maybe Lotus - new kid on the bloc. But since you would not have db Sinatra seems to be the best option. It is light and fast. You can do whatever architecture you want with it. Sevices, presenters, whatever. There is in Internet a lot of `recipes` for many kinds of configuration.

Comment: More [reading](http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-microframeworks-round/) than you ever planned to do on Ruby microframeworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just going to upvote some comments, but we try not to answer in comments, so I'll try to synthesize the relevant points:

Rails' infrastructure is designed to accomodate a fairly complex app, and is probably overkill for the sort of simple app you're talking about building. This matters because Rails embraces [Convention Over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), and the conventions are geared toward larger apps.
Here's a couple of examples (not an exhaustive list):

1. Rails separates routes into their own file, with individual controller classes for interacting with each type of resource. If you have only a handful of pages in your app, this can be more structure than you need.
2. Although you can tell it not to, Rails assumes by default that you want to use ActiveRecord (and that you have a database for it to talk to). It also assumes you'll want model classes, and that there's both enough of them and they're complex enough that they need their own directory of individual files.
3. The Rails Asset Pipeline is great for dealing with lots of complicated assets that require extensive preprocessing. It's also kind of a pain in the ass.

There are a number of Ruby-based microframeworks that are likely better suited to the sort of app you describe. [Sinatra](https://sinatrarb.com) is probably the most widely used. It makes few assumptions and is consequently lightweight, allowing you to establish whatever design patterns you want in your app. There are also [bunch of others](http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-microframeworks-round/) that might be worth considering.